# MVC 4 override AuthorizeAttribute not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authorize-attribute

I created a basic MVC 4 project.  Added the HomeController and Home\Index.cshtml and ContactUs.cshtml.
Add route in Global.asax for ContactUs.

Add a Folder Auth and add a class Auth.css in Auth folder.

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Net.Http;


namespace MvcApplicationTestProject1
{
    public class AuthAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        //public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
        //{
        //    HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
        //}        

        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            var response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Redirect);
            response.Headers.Add("Location", "http://www.google.com");
            actionContext.Response = response;
        }
        //MVC 4 Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute has IsAuthorized function but not AuthorizeCore
        protected override bool IsAuthorized(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

In HomeController

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // GET: /Home/  
        [Auth]       
        public ActionResult ContactUs()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

The problem is when run the code and visit http://localhost:[port number here]/Home/ContactUs, 
it does not hit on the override class AuthAttribute.

Does the code have something wrong?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? its not obvious...

Comment: I am trying to customize the [Authorize] to [Auth] and use it on cotrollers. This will provide flexibility for me to build my own authentication instead of using the standard membership.

Comment: This is what I try to achieve. Only diference is it is MVC 4 but not for MVC3. http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/05/04/asp-net-mvc-authentication-customizing-authentication-and-authorization-the-right-way.aspx

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your comment says you are trying to achieve what is in [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/05/04/asp-net-mvc-authentication-customizing-authentication-and-authorization-the-right-way.aspx), and yet you copied code not from that post at all, but from a previous SO post: [Using custom authorization in MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882407/using-custom-authorization-in-mvc-4) that was referring to Web API. And in reading that post you see the difference is in what AuthorizeAttribute you use. You are using `System.Web.Http` instead of `System.Web.Mvc`.

If you used the code that you referred to in your comment, then you'd find it would work:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplicationTestProject1
{
    public class AuthAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is triggered now.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user2130167 NP. Happy programming.

Comment: Thank you! Ridiculous that including a different namespace pointed me towards the wrong override for mvc4 which just doesn't 'work' and fails silently.

Comment: It's avoiding the below rule .AvoidUnsealedConcreteAttributesRule.please tell me how to fix this .my self i am using above code.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Five years later, still relevant.  Would be nice if there was a warning of some kind.

Comment: @Jack glad it still helps... too bad it is necessary though!